# how measure execution with try/except bad used

Tags: python, try-catch, execution

Sorry about my english. I need scrit to show the right use of try/except in Python. I try the  rigth and wrong way and wait for  more time execution in the wrong way, but I can't prove that. I'm  beginer  with python.
I think only those lines that generate exceptions need to be in try block, n=1000000 will not generate an exception, I know, but is only for testing under the same conditions.
Regards.
Daniel

```
from time import time
#**************************
#Right use, I suppose
#**************************
start1=time()
try:
    n=1000000
except:
     print('Error en el ingreso')  
while n>=0: #out try is more fast?
       n-=1 #out try is more fast?
end1=time()#end mark good time
good=end1-start1
print('Time right used: {}'.format(good))
#**************************
#Wrong use, I suppose
#**************************
start2=time()
try: 
    n=1000000
    while n>=0:#in try is more slow?
       n-=1    #in try is more slow?
except:
    print('Error en el ingreso')         
end2=time()
bad=end2-start2#end mark bad time
print('Time wrong used: {}'.format(bad))

if bad>=good:
    print('Bad use take more time')
else:
    print('Good use take more time')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to note:

- `time.time()` returns the "wall-clock" time. This is a bad metric to use when benchmarking code. What you want to measure is how much time the CPU took to complete the code. For this you can use the `timeit` module.
- When benchmarking, try to write the smallest representative code that takes short time to run, so that you can execute it a lot of times and take the average (using `timeit`).

On to the example:

```
from timeit import timeit

def loop_with_tryexcept():
    try:
        n = 10_000
        while n >= 0:
            n -= 1
    except:
        print("Error")

def loop_without_tryexcept():
    n = 10_000
    while n >= 0:
        n -= 1


"""
python -i test.py

>>> timeit('loop_with_tryexcept()', setup='from __main__ import loop_with_tryexcept', number=1000)
0.49678000000017164
>>> timeit('loop_without_tryexcept()', setup='from __main__ import loop_without_tryexcept', number=1000)
0.5228376000000026

# It seems a tiny bit faster. Or is it?


>>> timeit('loop_with_tryexcept()', setup='from __main__ import loop_with_tryexcept', number=1000)
0.4899204999999256
>>> timeit('loop_without_tryexcept()', setup='from __main__ import loop_without_tryexcept', number=1000)
0.4767956000000595

# Nope, it was just randomness introduced by the CPU.
"""
```

You can see there is no difference in speed when wrapping code in a try/except block.